# Вживання слів "підодіяльник" та "підковдра"

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм, калька, українські-словники

В українській мові існує слово "підковдра", але в Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови я знайшов слово "підодіяльник", і хоч багато людей кажуть, що це калька з російської. Отож, виходить якщо людина використає слово "підодіяльник" ми не зможемо її виправити, адже вона може сказати, що знайшла таке слово в словнику. То чи можна все таки вживати данне слово, и все ж краще використовувати слово "підковдра"?

Comment: @Анатолій, Ваше запитання, по-моєму, несуттєво відрізняється від наведеного Марією. Отож я голосую за його закриття. Якщо Ви не згодні — будь ласка, обґрунтуйте.

Answer (score 1):

В СУМ-11 є обидва слова

> **[ПІДОДІЯЛЬНИК](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidodijaljnyk)**  Легкий чохол, який одягають на ковдру або прикріплюють до неї; підковдра.
>
> **[ПІДКОВДРА](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkovdra)** Те саме, що підодіяльник.

У програмі [**"Експрес-урок української"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaTIFhJ-FLM) Олександр Авраменко вказує, що найбільш доцільно використовувати ***"підковдра"***, коли ми говоримо про легкий чохол, який одягають на ковдру.

*На мою думку, в усній мові можемо вживати обидва варіанти (зокрема в оточені, яке Вас розуміє).*